# Элемент Point (org.springframework.data.geo.Point) сохраняется в Postgresql как Bytea. Почему и как мне сохранить координаты точки?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-mvc, spring-data

Начал изучать Java и Spring framework.
Делаю задание, часть которого - хранение набора точек с привязкой к какой-то площади (не важно к какой, к вопросу это не относится) и поиск ближайшей из набора к заданной точке.

**Создал такую сущность:**

```
package com.parkinghelper.parker.domain;

import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.geo.Point;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table(name = "parking_place")
@Data
public class ParkingPlace {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private Point coordinate;
    
    private Boolean isFree;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "area")
    private ParkingArea area;


    public ParkingPlace() {
    }
}
```

Столкнулся с проблемой, что Sping Data создает таблицу с полем точки (coordinate) сохраняет как `Bytea`. Соответственно в запросе обработать этот набор не получается.

[image: Структура таблицы]

В самом PostgreSQL есть тип `Point` и если предварительно создать таблицу с этим типом, то hibernate (если я правильно понял, то именно эта реализация JPA отвечает за работу с БД. Подправьте если это не так) не может подключиться к такой таблице созданной сущностью.

При попытке взять данные из БД выпадает исключение

```
 "could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize"
```

Полный stacktrace выглядит страшно.

Собственно вопрос следующий. Почему такая несогласованность типов у Spring Data и PostgreSQL. Как с этим бороться (хотелось бы использовать стандартный тип `Point` из БД, т.к. нужны фишки для работы с ним в запросе)?

Быть может версии не стыкуются или же мне нужно использоваться другую СУБД, например Oracle?

В интернете толком не нашел информации по этому вопросу, только то, что можно использовать PostGis для таких целей.

**Property следующие:**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=123456
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true


spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

server.port=8080

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

**Репозиторий:**

```
@Repository
public interface ParkingPlaceRepository extends JpaRepository<ParkingPlace,Long> {
}
```

Версия: PostgreSQL 11.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit

Версия Java: 10.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Не надо привязываться к классам из Spring Data. Поскольку данные классы не могут быть энтитями в таком виде как они есть, и нельзя соответственно конвертировать их в объекты.

Перед тем как использовать классы в сущьностях убедитесь что они имплементируют `java.util.Serializable` интерфейс.

Comment: По поводу классов Spring Data понял, спасибо.

Можете посоветовать
Либо какой класс можно использовать для того, чтобы читать Point из postgres'a?
Либо каким образом можно создать свой класс, чтобы была возможность его сериализовывать в тот же Point? (Какая нибудь информация на эту тему может известна?)

Comment: Обычный pojo, поищи в интернете полно примеров.